# JSON merge arrays and UNIQUE or DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, json

In my MySQL database I have a table `features` with this structure:

```sql
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| val   | json    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

When I select everything from it, like so, I get the following:

```sql
mysql> select * from features;
+----+----------------------------------+
| id | val                              |
+----+----------------------------------+
|  1 | ["apple", "banana", "orange"]    |
|  2 | ["apple", "orange", "pineapple"] |
|  3 | ["orange", "banana"]             |
|  4 | []                               |
+----+----------------------------------+
```

The value in the `val` column should always be an array of strings. This array can have any length (>= 0).

The question is:
How can I select all those array values in a single result set, not repeated? So that I get this result and use it in PHP:

```sql
+------------+
| arr_values |
+------------+
| apple      |
| banana     |
| orange     |
| pineapple  |
+------------+
```

The only constraint to solve this is that it should be compatible with MySQL v5.7.

Comment: Does the max elements count in JSON array exists and known?

Comment: There is no maximum count of elements in that array. It can be from 0 to any.

Comment: If so then the task cannot be solved in single query form - only stored procedure may help.

Comment: Ok, any solution is acceptable for me, as long as it runs on MySQL v5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If maximal amount of elements per JSON value is limited then (an example for not more than 10 elements)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT JSON_EXTRACT(features.val, CONCAT('$[', numbers.num, ']')) arr_values
FROM features, ( SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 4 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 5 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 6 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 7 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 8 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 9 ) numbers
HAVING arr_values IS NOT NULL;
```

If really the max array size is limited nevertheless (for example, 1000000) then it is possible to generate the dynamic table with proper amount of number. But stored procedure with iterational parsing and temporary table is more safe solution.

---

**UPDATE.**

Non-limited solution (stored procedure).

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_unique ()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (val JSON);
INSERT INTO temp 
    SELECT val 
    FROM features;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (val JSON);
cycle: LOOP
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tmp
        SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(val, '$[0]')
        FROM temp;
    DELETE 
        FROM temp
        WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(val, '$[1]') IS NULL;
    UPDATE temp
        SET val = JSON_REMOVE(val, '$[0]');
    IF 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM temp) THEN
        LEAVE cycle;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE temp;
SELECT DISTINCT * 
    FROM tmp
    WHERE val IS NOT NULL; 
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=415f8f957897b9df7784cc7342e167d7)

Comment: Thank you! This should work for me. But a non-limited solution would be better.

Comment: @MaxCruer Check that the tables/views `temp` and `tmp` NOT exists before procedure execution. Or alter their names in a procedure (for example, to something like `temp_in_get_unique_proc`) for to provide non-interference. If output is not huge you may set `ENGINE=Memory` for `tmp` (or even for both) - but be aware of "Not enough memory".

Comment: Ok, I will keep your warning in mind @Akina. Thank you anyway!